# Конвертация datetime MySQl

Tags: c#, mysql

Здравствуйте столкнулся с такой проблемой, из базы MySQL вытаскиваю данные в dataGridView, в таблице есть колонка с датой, значение которой - 00.00.000, создал событие на нажатие по строке dataGridView, при котором данные из выделенной строки попадают в dateTimePicker, но при выделении строки с датой 00.00.000 выходит ошибка

> Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = (bool)dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue ? Color.Red : SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            Int32 Row = (Int32)(System.Convert.ChangeType(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value, typeof(Int32)));
            DateTime Row2 = (DateTime)(System.Convert.ChangeType(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value, typeof(DateTime)));

            textBox1.Text = System.Convert.ToString(Row);
            dateTimePicker1.Value = Row2;

        }

    }
```

Comment: @Gena_2007: StackOverflow вывел на [багрепорт](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26054), в котором разработчики говорят, что это ожидаемое поведение:

> This is not a bug but expected behavior. Please check manual under connect options and set "Allow Zero Datetime" to true

![screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/acRT4xY.jpg)

Comment: Я в строке подключения указал этот параметр, при загрузке в datagrid проблем нет, но когда из datagrid в dateTimePicker,  ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите, в каком формате забирается дата из грида. MySQL хранит дату в формате гггг-мм-дд. Возможно, потребуется её преобразовать в дд.мм.гггг.